# What does the SQL # symbol mean and how is it used?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, symbols

Can someone please explain to me what the **`#`** symbol means in MS SQL Code.

I've tried Googling it, and even searching on StackOverflow, but can't seem to find the answer.

I feel like an idiot - having one of "those" days. Please help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

They normally prefix temporary tables.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)....

> Prefix local temporary table names
>   with single number sign (#table_name),
>   and prefix global temporary table
>   names with a double number sign
>   (##table_name).

Comment: Perhaps better to post a link for SQL Server 2005/2008 nowadays, even if info is still the same...?

Comment: What are the differences between this and a table variable via DECLARE?

Comment: What about hashtags after the name?, such as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16  SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases

Comment: @skan In that example the # is part of the name, and has no special meaning.

Answer (score 13):

The pound sign `#` is used to prefix [temporary tables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) and [procedures](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/459.cfm). A single instance (`#`) refers to a temporary object that lives/dies with the current session while a double instance (`##`) is a global object.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are correct if you're dealing with SQL Server, and it's clear that you are. But since the question title just says SQL, I should mention that there are some forms of SQL such as MySQL where a pound sign is used as an alternative commenting symbol.

```
#This is a comment.
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

Answer (score 5):

You could be seeing the # in the usage of a temporary table

```
SELECT
  *
FROM #myTempTable
```

Comment: Local temp tables. ## is for global temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

*#TEMPTABLE. Its actually a type of a temporary table that is scoped for that session.*