# What does # mean in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, comments

Does anyone know what something like `OR 1#` means in the context of mysql injection?

Comment: The `#` symbol has a few English names (number, octothorpe, hex, hash, sharp) that you *can* Google :)

Comment: :) thanks for helping me find completely unrelated pages! in all seriousness, I did Google for mysql pound symbol, etc, before asking and just got pages on british pounds

Comment: Ironically, this is now the top result if you search for `mysql hash symbol` and the second result for `mysql octothorpe`.

Comment: Top result for sharp sql, and still can't find the answer :/

edit : I've found an answer in third page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166117/what-does-the-sql-symbol-mean-and-how-is-it-used

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is MySQL's version of the line comment delimiter. In standard SQL, the line comment delimiter is `--`.

```
-- This is a standard SQL comment.
# This is a MySQL comment.
```

So in the context of SQL injection, if the attacker knows you're using MySQL he may use it to abruptly terminate the malicious SQL statement, causing MySQL to ignore whatever is behind the `#` and execute only the stuff that comes before it. This is only effective against single-line SQL statements, however. Here's an example:

Input:

> Username: `fake' OR 1#`
>   Password: `pass`

Resultant SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'fake' OR 1#' AND password = 'pass'
```

Which is executed as this, which returns *every row*:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'fake' OR 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the start of a comment. It means that anything after that will be skipped by the parser.

Comment: @JD: a-ha, to protect against sql-injections we need more lines in our queries (irony) ;-)