# what is the correct syntax for insert into php mysql. W or W/O session variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, insert

I have tried a lot of syntax trials with single quotes and $session variables, now i decided to put the session variables in regular variables for less syntax complications.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        } 
        if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) {
            die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
        }


    $this_email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $this_password = $_SESSION['pw'];
    $this_number = $_SESSION['phone'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_accounts(Email, Password, Phone#) VALUES ('$this_email','$this_password','$this_number')");
    if (!$sql) {
      echo mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
```

This is the error i get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: If you can, it's probably better to just use a column name that doesn't need to be in backticks to begin with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300669/what-does-mean-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

Column names may have `basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore`. All other characters will need to be in backticks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

so try:

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts(Email, Password, `Phone#`)
```

You also should update your driver and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Phone#` has a special character in it (`#`) you need to write it in backticks!

Furthermore I would recommend you to use the PDO or mysqli lib as well as prepared statements, because the mysql library is deprecated.

Comment: It's not a problem just because it's non-alphanumeric. `#` actually means something.