# Like operator in SQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables as:

Table1:

```
Handle       Name Description
OP1,BP1,33:A OP1  OP1 Desc
```

Table2:

```
Handle       Attribute Value
OP1,BP1,33:A Z_MARK    X
```

Table3:

```
Handle CurrentHandle ValuationPoint
Z:Y:Z  OP1,BP1,33:#  Disc Roll
```

Now i am trying to join the three tables so my query that i have come up with is:

```
Select t1.Handle , t1.Name , t1.Description from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Handle = t1.Handle
inner join table3 t3 on t2.Handle like CONCAT('%', t3.CurrentHandle, '%')
```

But as usual i am getting no records.

In the three tables table1 and table2 have same value for column Handle where as table2's Handle is almost similar to table3's CurrentHandle Column.

So i was trying to join these three tables with Like clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebas.It isn't returning any result Sebas.

Comment: If it was my db, I'd be sorely tempted to normalise it.

Comment: Why it should retun a result? `OP1,BP1,33:A` isn't `LIKE '%OP1,BP1,33:#%'` Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes thats the point. OP1,BP1,33:A is almost similar to OP1,BP1,33:#. So i thought of implementing like clause

Comment: If not normalize then add/use a surrogate key to avoid certain complexities of this nature.

Comment: My understanding is that '#' is a wildcard in like statements. But I might be wrong here

Comment: @sebas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300669/what-does-mean-in-sql

Comment: right, I was wrong

Comment: Allowed wildcards are `.` , `%` and `*` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are compare # too... try to replace it:

```
Select 
      t1.Handle , 
      t1.Name , 
      t1.Description 
from 
      table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
      on t2.Handle = t1.Handle
      inner join table3 t3 
      on t2.Handle like CONCAT('%',REPLACE( t3.CurrentHandle,'#',''), '%')
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.. Yes i was missing the replace function in my query.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it:

```
Select t1.Handle , t1.Name , t1.Description from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Handle = t1.Handle
inner join table3 t3 on t2.Handle like CONCAT('%', t3.CurrentHandle, '%')
```

Returns nothing as `OP1,BP1,33:A` != `%OP1,BP1,33:#%`

This is assuming the `#` at the end of the `t3`.`CurrentHandle` is you describing a variable or unwanted character, then use:

```
SELECT t1.Handle , t1.Name , t1.Description 
FROm table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Handle = t1.Handle
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.Handle LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING(t3.CurrentHandle, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(t3.CurrentHandle)-1)., '%')
```

Comment: This query works even if the last character isn't a`#`, it can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOUNDEX for fuzzy search/compare (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

```
Select t1.Handle , t1.Name , t1.Description from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.Handle = t1.Handle
inner join table3 t3 on SOUNDEX(t2.Handle) = SOUNDX(t3.CurrentHandle)
```

Comment: Or even the `SOUNDS_LIKE()` function.