# understanding existing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to read some exiting SQL queries written for MS SQL server.

I don't have access to database, table names etc.. Just raw query format...And I need to do some analysis on the fields required..

I need some help in understanding what certain query statements are doing...such as in the following block...

```
    select FIELD1, x2.FIELD2
    into #temp
    from #temp1 x1 join #temp2 x2
    on x1.FIELD1 = x2.FIELD2
    and x1.FIELD3 = x2.MAXOCCUR
```

I have basic SQL understanding.. But I need to understand couple of things....Why does 'into' and 'from' statements have a '#' infront of table names.....what are x1 and x2 in this case. Why not just say

```
          temp1.FIELD1 = temp2.FIELD2    instead of
          x1.FIELD1 = x2.FIELD2
```

.....Am I missing something or is this query formed weird to begin with....I understand joins etc...

Can someone help me out...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166117/what-does-the-sql-symbol-mean-and-how-is-it-used

Comment: ok. thank you guys... so # is used for temp tables and also one can alias table names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is selecting from two already temp existing temp tables into a new temp table. The `x1.FIELD1` is called aliasing. It's used so you don't have to type full table names when writing the query

Comment: thank you. I just did not know what to search for earlier...really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the # signs indicate a TEMPORARY table.

x1 and x2 are used as "table alias" in this query.  Yes, you could write

```
temp1.FIELD1 = temp2.FIELD2 instead of x1.FIELD1 = x2.FIELD2
```

but, consider if the tables had long names.  Then using an alias makes the query easier to read (for humans.  the computer doesn't really care).